# BufferReader in Java

Tags: java, outputstream

I have a problem with BufferReader and OutputStream in Java. My aim: when you insert something from a keyboard - it goes to the file. How should I correct my code?

```
import java.io.*;

class IntoFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try {
            BufferedReader sisse = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print ("Insert something: ");
            String s = sisse.readLine();

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            OutputStream valja = new FileOutputStream(new File(args[0]));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                }
            valja.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println ("I/O: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you could read the API http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html . There's a method called write(Byte[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use Scanner and PrintWriter

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>javac Dmitri.java

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java Dmitri
test
woohoo
quit

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>more out.txt
test
woohoo
quit

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>
```

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Dmitri {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("out.txt");
        while(in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            out.println(line);
            out.flush(); // not necessary every time, but simple to do so
            if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT")) break;
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for Scanner. While at University, we were always made to use a propriety package that was essentially a poor version of Scanner. Definitely a good class for this answer.

Comment: @obfuscation that's unfortunate. Sounds like a professor or TA just trying to show off their library. If they were doing their due diligence, they would have pounced on the opportunity to show their students how powerful the java core libraries are, and how to use them effectively. Knowing the core libraries of a language is (in my estimation) the first step to even being able to say "Yeah, I know that language."

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. In later projects, I always made a conscious choice to use standard libraries just to familiarise myself with them. After all, both can't and don't want to rely on proprietary code.

Answer (score 0):

HI I am providing a sample code through which you can write in the file after user enters characters or line from keyboard.

```
try{
    // Create file 
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write("Hello Java");
    //Close the output stream
    out.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

In the **our.write** pass the **line(variable)** string argument and the string will be written in that file.